# Bitscan forward test

Tags: c

My function is supposed to find the bit-index of `LSB1` in an integer.

My question is that how could I test if this works? I guess the function     expects a 32-bit unsigned integer but all attempts to test this proved unsuccessful. I don`t know if it is because of my architecture or something.

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>


int bitscanforward(uint32_t v) 
{

static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
assert(v);
return MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U) >> 27];

}


int main()

{

   uint32_t x = 0X05FEEEEE;
   int answer = bitscanforward(x);
   printf("Index of LS1B: ");
   printf( "%d", answer );

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: What did you test and what happened?

Comment: The test I did produced 0 as result.

Comment: Are you aware that constant is octal? It is odd in any case so it should produce zero as result.

Comment: A proper test includes all problematic patterns.

Comment: I`m still not getting the right results, I just edited my original post.

Comment: The presented program yields the (apart from the missing `\n`) correct output `Index of LS1B: 1`. With what machine and compiler do you get a wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to `typedef` your own `unit32`: Note that your version will **not work**, as `long long` is at least 64 bits). Instead use `stdint.h` as defined by the standard. There you will (very likely) find `uint32_t`, which is guaranteed to hold 32 bits.

To verify your code, you could use a unittest framework, or just call the function with well thought arguments and check the results (the framework does pretty much the same).

Note that the name of a function should represent what it actually does. Yours does not. For the given task, "find first one"/ffo is commonly used. Some compilers like gcc already have builtin functions for this (which directly map to assembler instructions on some CPUs).

Comment: If it can be called "find first one", then it can also be called BitScanForward

Comment: Thank you, could you give me example of  how should I call it?

Comment: Sorry long long should be of course long I edited it.

Comment: `long` is also not guaranteed 32 bits. Only a _minimum_ range is guaranteed for the internal integer types, not a max. range (just an ordering). What is the problem using the standard's way instead of homebrew? For the builtins, just refer to the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) - pick your version, "extensions to the C language", ... .